# Should the validity of the token be checked before sending the request or from the response returned?

Tags: axios, access-token, interceptor, refresh-token

I want to refresh access token if it is expired. Should I check Id token and refresh it before sending request with interceptors.request and refresh the token and make a new request or just check the interceptors.response and then refresh it. Which one is better way?

```
    axios.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('IdToken');
      if (token) {
        if (checkTokenExpired(token)) {
          await refreshTokens();
        }
      }
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
      config.headers['token'] = accessToken;
      return config;
    },
     error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
     }
    );

    axios.interceptors.response.use(
    res => {
      return res;
    },
    async err => {
      const originalConfig = err.config;
      if (err.response) {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
           try {
               refreshTokens();
            });
           } catch (_error) {
             return Promise.reject(_error);
           }
         }
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  );

  const checkTokenExpired = idToken => {
    if (idToken) {
      const decoded = jwtDecode(idToken);
      if (decoded && decoded['exp']) {
        return Date.now() - 1000 >= decoded['exp'] * 1000;
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the interceptor response and then refresh the token if needed. Because if you keep checking token validity each time, it'll increase memory usage. Whenever Axios interceptors get a failed response, then you can check and refresh the access token if needed.

Here's a sample code

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const originalRequest = error.config;
            const refreshToken = getCookie(REFRESH_TOKEN);
            if (error.response && error.response.status === 401 && refreshToken) {
                originalRequest._retry = true;
                const details = {
                    refresh_token: refreshToken
                };
                let formBody  = {} // form data
                const response = fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/auth/refresh-token`, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    },
                    body: formBody
                })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((res) => {
                        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.access.token}`;
                        return axios(originalRequest);
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        return Promise.reject(e);
                    });
                resolve(response);
            }

            if (
                error.response
          
            ) {
                throw error.response.data;
            }

            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
    }
);
```